# DoesNotExist at /en-us/ A template tag couldn't find the page with lookup arguments `{'reverse_id': u'home', 'site': 1} `

Tags: django-cms

I am currently going through the django-cms-demo.  I have been using the code found here:

> https://github.com/andrewschoen/django-cms-demo/tree/master/demo.

I had this working prior to adding the Poll app plugin.  I had been getting reverse matching errors when I add the Poll app plugin in the django-admin.  After a couple of fixes, I started getting the error below:

> "A template tag couldn't find the page with lookup arguments `{'reverse_id': u'home', 'site': 1}`. The URL of the request was: 'http'://example.com/en-us/"

Traceback:

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL:      'http'://127.0.0.1:8888/en-us/

```
Django Version: 1.5.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'cms',
 'mptt',
 'menus',
 'south',
 'sekizai',
 'reversion',
 'cms.plugins.text',
 'polls',
 'filer',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'cms.plugins.link',
 'cms.plugins.picture',
 'tinymce',
 'djangocms_column',
 'cmsplugin_filer_file',
 'cmsplugin_filer_image',
 'cmsplugin_filer_teaser',
 'cmsplugin_filer_folder',
 'cmsplugin_filer_video')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware')
```

Template error:
In template /home/vagrant/django_cms/demo_cms/templates/subpage_base.html, error at line 26
   A template tag couldn't find the page with lookup arguments `{'reverse_id': u'home', 'site': 1}`
. The URL of the request was: 'http'://example.com/en-us/
   16 :

17 :          {% placeholder sidebar %}

18 :

19 :

20 :           {% block sub_content %}{% endblock %}

21 :

22 :

23 : {% endblock %}

24 :

25 : {% block footer %}

26 :       {% show_placeholder 'footer' 'home' %}

27 : {% endblock %}

28 :

29 :

> Traceback:
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     140.                     response = response.render()
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
>     105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
>     82.         content = template.render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>     140.             return self._render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
>     134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>     830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>     74.             return node.render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
>     124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
>     134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>     830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>     74.             return node.render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
>     124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
>     134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>     830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>     74.             return node.render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/core.py" in render
>     106.         return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sekizai/templatetags/sekizai_tags.py" in render_tag
>     76.         rendered_contents = nodelist.render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>     830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>     74.             return node.render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
>     63.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>     830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>     74.             return node.render(context)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/core.py" in render
>     106.         return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/helpers.py" in render_tag
>     75.         data = self.get_context(context, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py" in get_context
>     468.         return _show_placeholder_for_page(**self.get_kwargs(*args, **kwargs))
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py" in _show_placeholder_for_page
>     436.     page = _get_page_by_untyped_arg(page_lookup, request, site_id)
>   File "/home/vagrant/django_cms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py" in _get_page_by_untyped_arg
>     107.             raise Page.DoesNotExist(body)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /en-us/
Exception Value: A template tag couldn't find the page with lookup arguments `{'reverse_id': u'home', 'site': 1}`
. The URL of the request was: 'http'://example.com/en-us/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
{% show_placeholder 'footer' 'home' %}
```

to:

```
{% show_placeholder 'footer' %}
```

Or add an `id` in your `home` page advanced settings called `home`